# Unable to compile C++ programs on CentOS

Tags: c, linux, unix, centos, rhel

I am getting the below error during ./configure.

```
configure:3429: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3451: gcc -m32 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -m32 conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3455: $? = 1
configure:3493: result: no

configure:3498: error: in `/root/cjk/1.x/src/externals/mecab':
configure:3500: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I have tried couple of solutions mentioned in internet but to no avail.
I have installed complete Developers package in the machine.
I have installed glibc-devel.i686 package as well.

Comment: Apparently, you are trying to (cross-) compile a 32-bit program/lib on a 64-bit system. This is possible, but you need to have 32-bit libs installed. Read your docs on how to do that on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue (CentOS 6.5 x64, gcc 4.4.7). I made sure `yum install glibc-devel.i686` was performed. A quick `find / -name "libgcc_s.*"` revealed:

```
/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgcc_s.so
```

So, perhaps you can try the workaround suggested [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/quick_fix_to_the_linker):

1. Add the absolute path to the gcc_s library on the link line, OR
2. (Recommended) If the library's filename has any major and minor version numbers appended to it, simply create a soft link to the library in the same location without the major and minor version numbers in the target filename.

I settled for compiling/linking my application statically by adding `-static` to my `gcc` invocation. So,

```
gcc -static -m32 ...
```

In that case make sure `yum install glibc-static.i686` is done.